# Temporarily disable the Swiperefreshlayout in a webview case

Tags: android, webview, swiperefreshlayout

I have created an android project where i include a Webview inside a Swiperefreshlayout (which i use it in order to reload the webview content) as shown below:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    

<WebView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

As you can see above the SwipeRefreshLayout is the parent of Webview.

This works well in most of the cases except the case where a google map appears in webview that is set to full screen.

In that particular case i cannot move the map downwards with my finger because the swipe down effect of the SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't allow me since it tries to reload the page.

So i need to deactivate somehow the  SwipeRefreshLayout for that particular page.
I tried to use mySwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false) with no success, because this disables the webview also since it is a child of SwipeRefreshLayout and everything stuck.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hi, Were you able to find the solution?